# MS Graph permissions - do the ones we have right now HAVE to be application level?

Tags: permissions, microsoft-graph-api

We developed an MS Teams app that makes two Graph calls:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats/${chatId}/members` & `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/${groupId}/Members`

In the manifest, there are two Application level permissions: `TeamMember.Read.Group` and `ChatMember.Read.Chat`. In Azure there are also two Application level permissions: `ChatMember.Read.All` and `TeamMember.Read.All`.

One of our clients wants to use the app, but their IT team does not like these Application level permissions and wants us to make them Delegated instead, or remove them.

The app *seems* to work when we remove the ResourceSpecific permissions from the manifest, but it does not work if we remove the Application level permissions from Azure, or try to change them to Delegated versions. It won't install and we get a permission error.

Is there something else that we can try that we may have missed? Do these Graph calls simply require Application level permissions to work and there's nothing we can do about that? We are not MS engineers and are not deeply experienced with Graph permissions.

Answer (score 0):

For the query "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats/${chatId}/members" the required delegated permissions are:

[image]

for query "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/${groupId}/Members" the required delegated permissions are:

[image]

Hope this helps.